# Issues on using svn to check out code from command line

Tags: svn, zsh

On my working directory, I tried to check out the code as follows:

```
svn co http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/mahout/trunk
```

But the system says:

```
zsh: command not found: svn
```

Does that mean that I did not install svn correctly. How to fix that?

Comment: That means that `svn` is not in your path.  How did you attempt to install svn?  What operating system are you using?

Comment: How did you install it? You can generally locate an executable using the command line "find / -name svn -print"

Comment: He's using Zsh shell, so it's a *nix box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More likely, it means that the svn executable is not on the system path. Create a symbolic link to it in /usr/bin

```
ln -s /full/path/to/executable/svn /usr/bin/svn
```

***UPDATE:***

I was going for the path of least resistance, but @derobert is right about root or sudo privileges needed for that. Never think about it, because I'm never a restricted user. Appending to `PATH` is probably the only way a restricted user can do it:

```
export PATH='$PATH:/full/path/to/svn/bin'
```

Ideally, that should go in one of your user preference startup scripts. It's usually something like `~/.profile`. In bash, it's `~/.bash_rc` or in some cases `~/.bash_profile`. Not sure about in Zsh, though, but look for something along those lines.

Comment: Umm, no, the right way is to change your `PATH` environment variable, or alternatively to use `/usr/local/bin`; `/usr/bin` should be left to the OS vendor.

Comment: According to which of the 1001 philosophies of *nix file system management? It doesn't matter.

Comment: Well, the Linux FHS at least. I'm guessing that someone with root access on something other than a desktop Linux (Ubuntu?) would have enough UNIX experience to know what command not found means, and how to solve it (or ask a much more specific question).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to search to see if svn is installed on your box...

you an do a 'which svn'

if nothing returns.. make sure you PATH variable is set to where your binaries are stored..

Comment: After typing "which svn", the system says "svn not found".  Then, how to find the installation path? It seems to me that I can check out code using svn from eclipse, which means that the svn has been installed. But I just do not know how to retrieve the installation information and use it from command line.

Comment: Yes, `which` only works in conjunction with the system path. Since `svn` isn't on your path, `which svn` wouldn't work. Look at @Jay's comment on your question, that should get you your svn executable path.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the SVN plugin in eclipse, that is not the same thing as the command line implementation of SVN. They are two separate packages. You will need to install the Subversion package seperately (preferably from your respective package manager).

Comment: I see. I confused the eclipse-based sVN with the SVN from the command line. So I have to install SVN separately in order to use it from command line, is that right?

Comment: I have seen people with this issue before and this is how we fixed it. I would not be surprised if the eclipse SVN plugin contained the executable for running Subversion via command line somewhere inside of it, but I imagine just installing the package would be the most hassle-free way of handling your problem.